# Rebasing a change after initial push

Tags: git, rebase

I created a local branch BR1 from master, made changes, and pushed them to remote branch BR1. Before it got reviewed I pushed a second change from local branch BR2 to remote branch BR2 and merged it to master.

Now I want to update my local BR1 to reflect the updates to remote master before I make further changes and push again. The usual stash/rebase/stash-pop procedure won’t work, because once I have pushed the initial changes in BR1, the branch has nothing to stash as far as Git is concerned. If I simply rebase BR1 from master, Git overwrites all of my changes with a pristine copy of master.

How can I do this?

**Later**: This is a response to Matt's suggestion that I use git merge.

First: be assured that I made a backup of the repo before I started. If I've messed up the repo completely, I can recover.

Merge seemed like a good way to solve the problem. (I learned to use Git from my former boss, who told us to use `git pull --rebase` and nothing else, but she's "former.")

I made a note of the last change I made to the branch I need to update, then entered:

```
git stash
git checkout dev-main (the branch we use for "main")
git pull --rebase
git checkout doc/new_devices (the branch I want to update)
git merge dev-main
git stash pop
```

(This is not exactly what Matt recommended, but it's the way we do things here, and I'm accustomed to it, and I think it should have produced the same result.)

I looked for the last change I made and found that it was not in the file. I don't know what state the branch is in, but it is not what I need.

The last line displayed by `git stash pop` was, "The stash entry is kept in case you need it again." I've never seen that before. (I never imagined that a successful `git stash pop` might *not* actually pop!) I don't know why git stash did that or what it means.

`git stash pop` also said that several files "need merge." I assume that means they have merge conflicts, but I found no merge conflict markers in them. As I understand it, `git merge` is a local operation, so I don't think `git pull` is appropriate here. Is there something else I need to do to insert the merge conflict markers and restore my files to their proper condition?

Some of the files with conflicts are ones that I have not changed in the doc/new_devices branch since I created it from dev-main. Why should Git think there is a merge conflict where dev-main has changed a file and I have not?

Comment: What do you mean by the "usual stash/rebase/stash-pop procedure won’t work"? Are you saying that when you have `BR1` checked out, `git status` is clean so there's nothing to stash? Also, when you "rebase BR1 from master" what branch is checked out and what command are you running? If you rebase `BR1` onto `master` it should not replace `BR1` with `master` unless all the changes on `BR1` are already in `master`, so I suspect something wasn't described perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* update `master` and rebase BR1 onto it, but now that you have pushed BR1 to the remote, that's not a good idea. Instead, update `master` and *merge* it into BR1:

```
# assume you are on BR1
git fetch origin master:master
git merge master
```

If there are merge conflicts, resolve them. Now you're all set.

Comment: I tried to follow Matt's advice but got very strange (and unsatisfactory) results. I've appended a description to the original question.

Comment: No you didn't try to follow my advice at all. You did something totally different (and weird). That's fine but don't associate it with me or this answer please.

Comment: I adapted your advice to my situation as well as I could. I'm sorry if the result did not meet your standards. I don't pretend to be a Git expert -- if I were, I wouldn't be here. /// I restored my backup and followed your *exact* advice, except for replacing `master` with `dev-main`. I got "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: (files listed) Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge. Aborting. /// The obvious next step would be to stash, merge, and pop. But that would take me back down the path you found so offensive. Advice?

Comment: Add and commit all your current changes before merging.